# Online password generator vs. offline counterparts? Are there widely adopted guidelines/recommendations?

Tags: passwords

Are there any widely adopted guidelines/recommendations in regard to online password generators? Are they recommended over offline generators, for example? If so with what justification?

References would be appreciated.

**NB:** this is *not* about password *managers*, but about password **generators** (and I include passphrase generators in that).

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Do you have an example of an online password generator? What kind of guidelines or recommendations are you looking for? Why are you asking this?

Comment: @Sjoerd The kind of guidelines is what I outlined with the NIST example. And no I won't give examples of online password generators, because I am not asking for a specific one.

Comment: It's not about analysing a specific generator, but to understand what you mean. Lastpass's website has an "generator". Is that what you mean? What about password generators prompted by your browser? Or do you mean a webpage that generates passwords. Then what do you mean by "offline"? A dedicated local app? Why would you think that there would be guidelines? What risks are you anticipating? The "guidelines" are about the process to generate, not where that generator might reside.

Comment: Consider services like bitwarden.com/password-generator/ and of course several other of the online password _managers_ offer to create a password online. An offline example would be [`pwgen(1)`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pwgen). The risks certainly stretch from XSS and other similar browser-based attacks to the possibility that a single big actor uses such services to get real-world passwords for precomputing rainbow tables or similar. Even `pwgen` seems to be safer than the other options as it generates many possible passwords at once and it's still up to the user to pick one.

Comment: No, I can't imagine there being guidance on using a website to generate passwords vs using a local app/process. I don't see the risks being significant enough to warrant specific thinking around this, specifically.

Comment: Wow, interesting. I can see all sorts of security issues arising from the use of online password generators. But thanks for your input! I'm almost tempted to ask the opposite question _already_, because I also researched a little and didn't find anything on my own -- thus the question. So the new question becomes: why not? But that'd be very much opinion-based, I'm afraid. I even gave examples for risks above but your response suggests that you don't see those as (significant) risks.

Comment: Yes, that would be opinion-based. A guideline is not likely to be produced until there is a systemic or inherent risk in doing something. Websites can be secured to a reasonable degree, so there is unlikely to be guidance suggesting that one should not use a website to generate passwords. If one existed, given the class of data we're talking about, then that same guidance would caution against any online password storage because the risks are the same or more so for storage. Because consider: a website isn't generating the password, your browser is.

Comment: @schroeder IMO that's a bold statement. Because neither laypeople nor you as tech-savvy can tell a 100% whether that assertion about "your browser generates the password" is true. And even if you could it would only be true for this point in time and (without visibility into the server-side) your individual request. Such a website could arguably act differently depending where you come from and so much more. So yeah, I see risks and therefore this question. But don't get me wrong: your view is very much appreciated, if only in ephemeral comments.

Comment: I think the password generator itself doesn't matter that much,  but the password itself does (for example Length is the most important characteristic of a good password: In general, the longer the password, the better.)

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, the underlying question is whether you can trust an online of offline password generator. And as usual when it comes to *trust*, the real questions are:

- can the *thing* be interested in attacking me? the answer may depend on the sensitivity on the informations you use, and who controls the *thing* (i.e. a foreign country might be interested in economic or military sensitive informations)
- is the *thing* correctly protected againts third party attacks? More specifically is its protection level at least as high as yours? Here again the answer will heavily depend on what your internal Information System contains...

Even if I tend to be more confident in local (meaning offline) things, I would avoid an obscure password generator with no source code and little reputation. But I currently use the one included in KeePass...

Comment: Well it comes to that underlying question whether online is deemed more or less secure than offline, sure. But I have indeed wondered about the absence of "official" guidance when for many other topics there are best practices advocated or even mandated -- in some contexts -- by national bodies. Regarding your second point: how would you even judge that, without any visibility into those services? And even open source doesn't change a lot, because you don't run them. A program which I compile myself is under my control. Big difference in my book.

Comment: Matter of trust... When I install a FreeBSD system, and its OpenSSH components, I *trust* that to respect the current security best practices, even I do not analyze the sources and compile it myself. Because they are *reputated* tools and I expect true security experts (what I do not pretend to be) to have analyzed them. And I would use them  without any question for governmental sensitive systems. But I would advocate against handling the same informations in Amazone cloud because it is under the control of the US government (I am from a EU country...).

Comment: That's a perfectly fair point, but I think it misses the part of "having control over something". Google also had a fairly good reputation to serve ads (in general, if you don't hate ads per-se). Yet they have also served malvertising campaigns. That's what I meant in the comments before on the question: when you analyze the online generator (suppose it has source provided) you still don't know if the next time around there isn't something nefarious going on. On systems under my control I could go to great lengths, including booting from r/o media to assure I can trust the generator.